# How to build spring based micro services state syncing after any node failure service crash

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, apache-zookeeper, netflix-eureka

I have few micro services, they accept the data from customer and process the request asynchronously, later customer can come and check the status, to make my platform my robust, I am planning to providing HA with running same setup services (atleat 2) and also registering with eureka, and also all my services are behind load balancer

Now I stuck at providing a solution if node failure or services goes down after accepting the request.

Lets say I have Service-A1 and Service-A2, both have same capability.

Now Service-A1 accepts the request and gave accepted response to customer then started processing the job and updating its intermediate results in db, now due to some node failure or service crash it could not complete the job.

In this case I want other service to auto detect(get notified) to continue, so it can read the job status and continue the job request for completion.

Is there any feature in  Spring Eureka or zookeeper to watch and notify other to continue. ?

Comment: At that point you're more into job management. Spring Cloud Task or Spring Batch might have some things for that. Spring Integration has distributed locks for zookeeper.

Comment: wont it be possible to register my all nodes to zookeeper and let zookeeper  notify the other others nodes when one of the nodes goes down ?

Comment: I'm not a zookeeper expert. But using curator you can setup watches.